# d3.zoom SVG G scaling and transforming with larger children

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have a situation where I have shapes being generated inside a G that are larger than the container.

I've tried a few approaches however most examples use set sizes and the number they use are hardcoded. I have also attempted to calculate the offsets, however the actual zoom.scaleTo() and then zoom.translateTo() output is different than what im passing to it.

Im pretty sure it something to do with when you scale with svg the coords are offset.

I have made a code pen where two Rects are added to a G and that G added to another G ref: this.g ( keeping alignment with my code )

Codepen [Here](https://codepen.io/NAEFH/pen/MWzLgOX)

Here is the function where this needs to happen:

```js
function setUpZoomAndCenterG() {
  let zoom = d3.zoom()
    .extent([
      [0, 0],
      [this.targetDiv.clientWidth, this.targetDiv.clientHeight],
    ])
    .scaleExtent([-1, 8])
    .on('zoom', (e) => {
      this.g.attr('transform', e.transform);
      // console.log(e)
    })

  this.svg.call(zoom);
  
  // Need to center the red boxes and fit them to the window. with a margin of 0.05/5%  it wuld also need to take into account landscape and portrait
  
  // zoom.scaleTo()
  // zoom.translateTo()
}
```

I want to the output to look like this:
[image]

Hopefully someone has encountered this before and can explain the procedure.

Answer (score 1):

GHere you go https://codepen.io/lary-Test/pen/mdQvzgr
what I added :

```
var transform = d3.zoomIdentity
    .translate((this.targetDiv.clientWidth / 2), 0).scale(this.targetDiv.clientHeight / (2000/*rect height*/))
    .translate(-2150/*rect with - rect.x*/, -100 /*rect y*/);
this.svg.call(zoom) // Adds zoom functionality
    .call(zoom.transform, transform);
```

First of i translated hirizontally to half of your total width, in order to center.
Then I scaled to your height, divided your rects height so the rects fit perfectly in the zomm height,
Then I translated again, verticaly to compensate for you `rect.y`
and horizontaly to compensate for first rect.x and first `rect.width` and halph of your second `rect.x`.

All your value are hard coded, but you should be able to use this with variable.

Good luck

Comment: Thanks for this info, d4.zoomIdentity was the key factor I was missing.